# NHibernate filters don't work with Session.Get

Tags: .net, nhibernate

I'm trying to implement a Soft-deletable repository. Usually this can be easily done with a Delete Event listener. To filter out the deleted entities, I can add a **Where** attribute to my class mapping. However, I also need to implement two more methods in the repository for this entity: **Restore** and **Purge**. Restore will "undelete" entities and Purge will hard-delete them. This means I can't use Where attribute (since it block out soft-deleted entities to any access)

I tried using **filters** instead. I can create a filter and enable or disable it within session to achieve the same result. But the problem is filters don't have any effect on Session.Get method (they only affect ICriteria based access).

Any ideas as to how solve this problem?

Thanks

Comment: Nope. Filters don't work on Get. They only affect criteria. I had to implement a different approach on the base repository only for Get and let Filter handle the other use cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

quote from Fabio Maulo:

> By design.Filters don't work with Get or Load since they mean: I want
>   load the entity with this ID.
>
> Dynamic filters work with HQL/Criteria and Collection(where enabled
>   for a collection) only when you use explicit joins or, more general,
>   when the QuerySpace of a filter match with the QuerySpace of a query.

Answer (score 0):

Would an IInterceptor work for this?

Looking at EmptyInterceptor I find that it has an OnLoad which I think you could use to intercept the object loading.